# How to use the collection()-function with saxonche

Tags: python, xquery, saxon, saxon-c

I am trying to use the `collection()`-function using the new `saxonche`-Python-Module (https://pypi.org/project/saxonche/).

I would expect, that it returns all XML-documents inside the current directory. Instead it just returns `None`.

My code looks like:

```py
from saxonche import PySaxonProcessor
from os import getcwd

with PySaxonProcessor(license=False) as proc:
    print(proc.version)
    xq = proc.new_xquery_processor()
    xq.set_query_base_uri(getcwd())
    xq.set_query_content("collection('.')/node()")
    r = xq.run_query_to_value()
    print(r)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I would try `collection('?select=*.xml')`

Comment: Hi please add your sample `xml` and data that you want to extract from it.

Comment: @MartinHonnen – I've already tried this, which also returns `None`...

Comment: @Hamed_gibago thanks for your comment. I've just want to read the whole XML-file. The structure is not relevant.

Comment: I added some error reporting: 
`if r is None and xq.exception_occurred:
        print(xq.error_message)` 
This prints: `Base URI must be an absolute URI: /home/......`
This looks like a possible bug. Investigating it further

Comment: No, it does not look like a bug to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get the suggested `collection('?select=*.xml')` to work if I use e.g.

```
from pathlib import Path
```

and then set

```
xq.set_query_base_uri(Path('.', 'foo.xml').absolute().as_uri())
```

Comment: Thanks! It's a litte bit weird to me, why the name of any file is needed – but it works :)

Comment: I think `xq.set_query_base_uri(Path('.').absolute().as_uri() + '/')` will also work, if that is less weird than perhaps use that. The problem is to, first of all have a URL and not a file path, and to make sure we select relative to the directory contents so either inventing a dummy file for the base URI or ensuring the URI ends in `/` should do.

Answer (score 1):

For the method *set_query_base_uri* the documentation (i.e. https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-c/doc12/html/saxonc.html#PyXQueryProcessor-set_query_base_uri) states:

> **set_query_base_uri(self, base_uri)**
>
> Set the static base URI for the query.
>
> Args:
> base_uri (str): The static base URI; or None to indicate that no base URI is available

Therefore we need to supply URI as a string. See another solution below which is based on the first one:

```
  from saxonche import PySaxonProcessor
  from os import getcwd

  with PySaxonProcessor(license=False) as proc:
    print(proc.version)
    xq = proc.new_xquery_processor()
    xq.set_query_base_uri('file://'+getcwd()+'/')
    xq.set_query_content("collection('?select=*.xml')")
    r = xq.run_query_to_value()
    print(r)
```

Comment: I think your suggestion `xq.set_query_base_uri('file://'+getcwd()+'/')` does work on Linux, MacOs and wherever the file directory separator is the forwards slash `/` but on Windows for `getcwd()` I get e.g. `C:\Users\marti\PycharmProjects\SaxonC1199LocalWheelTest1` and that way, while not throwing an error on trying to set some oddly formed mixture of a Windows file path and a URI e.g. `file://C:\Users\marti\PycharmProjects\SaxonC1199LocalWheelTest1/` as the base URI, the query doesn't find anything.

Comment: So I am all ears for easier cross-platform solution in Python but I would think that my suggestion to use `xq.set_query_base_uri(Path('.', 'foo.xml').absolute().as_uri())` or `xq.set_query_base_uri(Path('.').absolute().as_uri() + '/')`  is safer/has better cross platform compatibility.

Comment: Yes I agree. I am now looking at accepting a _Path_ as an argument which should work as a cross-platform solution.

Comment: I have created the feature request for adding the Path as argument to set_query_base_uri here: https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/5833

Comment: as an alternative the following code can be used to solve the file separator issue:
`import os
os.path.sep`