# Python saxonpy returns I/O error when transforming XML

Tags: python, xml, saxon

I am trying to perform XSLT transform using [saxonpy](https://pypi.org/project/saxonpy/) with Python code as attached:

```
from saxonpy import PySaxonProcessor
import os

class XMLProcessor:

    proc = PySaxonProcessor(license = False)

    def processXSLT2(self, sourceXmlDocPath, xsltStyleSheetPath):
        # https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-c/doc1.2/html/saxonc.html#PyXslt30Processor
        print(self.proc.version)
        self.proc.set_cwd(os.getcwd()) #set the CWD first
        xsltproc = self.proc.new_xslt30_processor()
        output = xsltproc.transform_to_string(source_file = sourceXmlDocPath, 
                                                stylesheet_file = xsltStyleSheetPath)

        return output
```

In my main py file, it is called using XMLProcessor.processXSLT2(XMLProcessor, LOCAL_XML_FILE,  os.environ['LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT'] + '/metadata.xsl')

However, the console shows this error message:

```
Saxon/C 1.2.1 running with Saxon-HE 9.9.1.5C from Saxonica
Error 
  I/O error reported by XML parser processing D:\git\lambda\data\test.xml: unknown protocol: d
```

Comment: The problem, I suppose, is the Windows file path `D:\git\lambda\data\test.xml` (your code doesn't show exactly where you construct it) being somehow treated by Saxon as a URL. It might be worth trying whether the fix from https://stackoverflow.com/a/75143880/252228 to use e.g. `from pathlib import Path` and e.g. `source_file=Path(sourceXmlDocPath).absolute().as_uri()` helps here as well. Anyway, using the SaxonC 12 saxonche official package would make it easier in the future to test/check/fix your code.

Comment: Yes, I think @MartinHonnen is right. The inputs to the XSLT process are URIs, not filenames, and Windows helpfully muddies the waters by having a filename syntax that looks like, but isn't, a URI syntax. It might be as simple as putting `file:///` in front of the filename.

Answer (score 1):

You're supplying a Windows filename to an interface that expects a URI.

You're also using a product that's very out of date: please move forward to SaxonC 12.x.